# Intellij on Mac OSX not showing the javadoc

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I am using the latest version of Intellij Idea v14 on Mac OSX Yosemite. The IDE is not showing the javadoc for the core Java classes when I use the Quick Documentation option(^J): I'm getting a blank popup box. Here is how it appears:

[image: Documentation popup with blank javadoc content]

I'm guessing the sources are not attached. Intellij is using the JDK6 provided by Apple as it is the recommended version on Mac. How do I fix this? Where can I download the sources for JDK6 by Apple or is there a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and attach sources for your JDK in project structure dialog, specifically in *SDKs/Sourcepath* tab

[image].

Other alternative is to download for example Oracle JDK which has the sources bundled with it.

I'm not using Apple JDK so I'm not sure where to download the sources, but [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677395/java-jdk6-source-for-mac-osx-lion) might help with that.

Hope this helps.

Path to the src.jar for Apple's 1.6 JDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6/Contents/Home/src.jar

Comment: I was trying to download the Apple java developer package from the apple developer site: [Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)

Filtered the results using "java" keyword and got some results. Now I'm confused between 2 versions.

1) Java for OS X 2013-005 Developer Package.
2) Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 17 Developer package.

I'm currently on Mac OS X Yosemite(v10.10). So which among the above two should I download?